# Express expectation value of a joint distribution over a discrete and continuous random variable

Tags: expected-value, joint-distribution, integral, measure-theory

Let $Y$ be a discrete random variable and let $X$ be an (absolutely) continuous random variable and $f(X, Y)$ a function of these two random variables. Let $P(X, Y)$ be the joint probability measure. I am now wondering how to properly write the joint expectation value
$\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)]$? I would write something like:
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)] = \sum_{y} \int f(x, y) dP(X=x, Y=y),$$
but I think this cannot be quite right because I shouldnt integrate over y.
So I would like to know how to write it down, both in terms of a Lebesgue integral, i.e., with respect to a probability measure $dP$, and as a Riemann Integral where I would integrate with respect to $dx$. Do I somehow have to split the probability measure up into a conditional and a marginal one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For what is ac the abbreviation?

Comment: So then I would rewrite $dP(X=x, Y=y)$ as $f_{X,Y}(x, y) d\lambda d\mu$ ? (where $d\mu$ shall denote the counting measure). Is that correct? But how would I proceed with that density, since Y is discrete

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that? What does it mean that $d\lambda$ has discrete support and what does it imply? Also, a discrete random variable does not have a density, right? So how could I write the discrete random variable $Y$ in a joint density $f_{X, Y}(x, y)$?

Comment: And do I have to write $d\lambda d\mu$ (where $\mu$ is the counting measure)? I.e., do I have to integrate over the counting measure as well or could I somehow write it only in terms of an integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure $d\lambda$?

Comment: Thanks again. What exactly do you mean by discrete support? The counting measure can be defined on any arbitrary set, no? And you equation, where exactly is the density in the integral?

Comment: Also is the answer in 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448240/joint-pdf-of-discrete-and-continuous-random-variables
wrong? Because in that answer it is being said that a discrete and a countinuous RV cannot have a joint density

Comment: That answer is correct. There will not be a joint density (either with respect to Lebesgue or counting measure) of a discrete and continuous random variable.

Comment: Hi can you elaborate on why that is?

Comment: for example, if $X$ is continuous and $Y$ is discrete, then consider the support of $(X, Y)$: because $Y$ is discrete and thus takes almost surely countably many values, the support of $(X, Y)$ is a Lebesgue-null set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore there is no joint density with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Similarly, the support of $(X, Y)$ is not countable because $X$ is continuous, so $(X, Y)$ cannot have a joint density with respect to counting measure

Comment: Okay, so there is really never a chance to find a joint density for a continuous and a discrete RV?

Comment: Yes, at least not with respect to Lebesgue or counting measure on the product space. You can try to define things like the [mixed joint density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case) (which isn't a density with respect to Lebesgue or counting measure, but with respect to the product of the marginal dominating measures), but in my opinion that's just obscuring the conditioning that's going on behind the scenes

Comment: So what I have read in a book however, is, that a joint distribution $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}$ of a continuous RV $X$ and a discrete RV $Y$ can have a density with respect to the product of the Lebesgue measure and the counting measure. So that is possible then, right?

Comment: yes, that’s what I meant in my last comment by “mixed joint density”

Comment: ah ok thx. And what did you mean by "but in my opinion that's just obscuring the conditioning that's going on behind the scenes"?

Comment: I meant that in most cases, when you want to know the "mixed joint density" of two random variables, you usually need to know the conditional distribution of one given the other. In that case you'll arrive at formula $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$. So in a way, you don't need to know the mixed joint density at all. The important part is the conditional distribution.

Comment: So I have just re-read your reasoning why there cannot be a joint density for $X$ continuous and $Y$ discrete w.r.t to Lebesgue measure from the 01.June. So is the problem that the support of $(X, Y)$ is not a null set w.r.t. to the joint probability measure $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}$ but it is w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure and hence the theorem of Radon Nykodim is not applicable? But I thought the implicatoin for absolute continouity would be the other way round: I.e., that if $A$ is a $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}$ Nullset it also has to be a Lebesgue Nullset?

Comment: And do conditional densities w.r.t. to Lebesgue measure exist in the case that $X$ is continuous and $Y$ is discrete, i.e., sth like $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$?

Comment: You have also linked to:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case
and you have pointed out that this is not a density w.r.t to Lebesgue measure. So then we would not be allowed to write sth like $\int g(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x,y)=\int g(x, y) f_{X, Y}(x, y) dxdy$?
And you also mention that this mixed density is a density "with respect to the product of the marginal dominating measures". Do you mean by that, that it is a density w.r.t to the prodcut of the Lebesgue measure and the counting measure?

Comment: If $X$ is continuous and $Y$ is discrete, then the support of $(X,Y)$ is a Lebesgue-measure-zero set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consequently, *if* the joint distribution $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}$ were absolutely continuous w.r.t. 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure (say, with density $f$), then it would be the constant zero measure: $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(A) = \int_{A \cap \text{supp}(X, Y)} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = 0$ for all Borel $A$. This would contradict $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}$ being a probability measure, so it can't happen. A conditional density w.r.t. Lebesgue measure for $X$ given $Y$ can still exist in this case.

Comment: "So then we would not be allowed to write sth like  $\int g(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x,y)=\int g(x, y) f_{X, Y}(x, y) dxdy$?" Correct.
"Do you mean by that, that it is a density w.r.t to the prodcut of the Lebesgue measure and the counting measure?" Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks again! Is the Product of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and counting measure $\eta$, $\lambda \otimes \eta$, a product measure, i.e., is $\lambda \otimes \eta = \lambda \eta$?

Comment: By "product of Lebesgue measure and counting measure", I meant the product measure obtained from Lebesgue measure and counting measure. I'm not sure what you mean by "$\lambda \nu$" though. If it's something like a point-wise product (i.e., $(\lambda\nu)(A)=\lambda(A)\nu(A)$), then that's not the same thing as product measure. But if you're using that notation to denote product measure (i.e., $(\lambda\nu)(A\times B)=\lambda(A)\nu(B)$), then that's what I mean as well.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant the latter. So just generally speaking: The product measure of two measures is well defined right? I.e., you cannot obtain a product measure out of any two arbitrary measures? I suppose this relates to my other question that you have answered (joint probability measure)

Comment: The product measure of two $\sigma$-finite measures always exists and is unique (this includes the case of probability measures). When the measures aren't $\sigma$-finite, a product measure exists, but may not be unique. In any case, most measures people work with are $\sigma$-finite, and for those measures there is always a unique, well-defined, product measure. Regarding your last sentence, let me also stress again that a joint probability measure is not always a product measure; it's a product measure iff the RVs are independent.

Comment: Hi and sorry that I am bringing this up again. But I have just reread our discussion here and what I am not sure about is the following: the Mixed joint density as defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case is the radon nikodym derivative of the joint distribution $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}$ w.r.t. to the product (measure) of lebesgue and counting measure. Is that statment correct? And if so, does that imply furthermore, that X and Y must be independent? So does that mean that such a mixed joint density can only exist if X and Y are independent?

Comment: Here I assumed as above that Y is discrete and X continuous.
Moreover, if a mixed joint density $p_{x,y}$ is given, can we always dissect it into two densities $p_{y|x}$ which would be a (conditional) density w.r.t. counting measure and $p_x$ which would be a density w.r.t. Lebesuge measure. I.e., given $p_{x,y}$, can we always write $p_{x,y}=p_{y|x} p(x)$ or do we need additional assumptions for that?

Comment: you're correct that the mixed joint density in that link is the Radon Nikodym derivative of the product of Lebesgue and counting measure, but it doesn't make any assumptions about the independence of $X$ and $Y$. Moreover, the general conditions under which you can decompose a joint measure/density into a conditional and marginal component falls under various [disintegration theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem), which would be too much to discuss in comments

Comment: Okay thanks again for your answer!
So maybe I am confusing again what exactly is understood under the term "product of two measures". But I thought the product measure (so here the product of lebesgue and counting measure) is a very specific construct, which is the product of the two marginal measures involved. And for that to hold we need independence. So is that product of lebesgue and counting measure here in our case not this product measure which is given by the product of the two marginals?

Comment: And regarding the dissection of the joint density into a conditional and marginal density: First, do the same rules apply for densities as for probability measures, when trying to dissect a joint density (probability measure)? And second, does your answer imply that generally speaking, when given a joint density, we cannot necessarily dissect it into a conditional and marginal density? I.e., must specific conditions be met that this is possible?

Comment: Independence is only meaningful relative to a joint probability measure. You can't just say "Lebesgue measure and counting measure are independent", because that doesn't specify the joint measure. The product measure is a specific way of building a measure out of two measures such that the two marginals are independent (that's in fact the probabilistic characterization of product measures). As for your second question, yes there are technical conditions that need to be met for conditional densities to exist

Comment: Okay sorry I still havent completely got it. So if we say the joint probability measure $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t the product of the Lebesgue and counting measure, then this means that a density (radon nykodym derivative) $p_{X, Y}$ exists, right? However, what I dont understand is, what is that "product of the Lebesgue and counting measure"?I.e., how do I write that down in mathematical terms? I always thought that would be sth like $\lambda \otimes \mu$ (where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure and $\mu$ is the counting meausre). But this is exactly the product measure

Comment: I.e., this would be the meausre that is equal to the product of the marginals. From your answer I realize that this "product of the lebesgue measure and counting measure" doesnt need to be the product measure, but what is it then?

Comment: I actually did mean that "product of Lebesgue measure and counting measure" is exactly a product measure. I was trying to point out that there are other measures on the product space whose marginals are Lebesgue measure and counting measure.

Comment: ok so does that mean that a "product measure" does not necessarily have to be dissectable in the measures involved?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure
I thought that "product measure" is a fixed term that always means that you can dissect that product measure into the product of the two measures as in the wikipedia link

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how we got to this point anymore . A "product measure" _is_ the product of measures.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just realized my error in thinking. Independence would be required if the joint distribution Was equal to the product measure of the marginal distributions. And this ofc has nothing to do with the product of lebesgue and counting measure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be thought of as a companion answer to [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/525342/97872) to your related question about expectations with respect to joint distributions.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$, with $X$ absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure and $Y$ discrete.
Let $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}$ be their joint distribution.

Then the general formula for the expectation of $f(X, Y)$ will be
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)]
= \int_{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}} f(x, y) \, \mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(d(x, y))
$$
by either the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) or the [change of variables formula for pushforward measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula), or however else you want to call it.
This formula uses neither of the assumptions on $X$ and $Y$ (it only assumes that the expectation exists).

Alternatively, the [law of iterated expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), as mentioned in the other answer, can be used to yield either
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y) \mid X]]
$$
or
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y) \mid Y]].
$$
Again, this does not use the assumptions on $X$ and $Y$, only the existence of the expectation.
In practice, one of these two forms might be easier to compute than the other, so it's up to you to choose which one to use.

In both cases, you'll probably want to know a conditional distribution of one of the variables with respect to the other, which I'll go over next.

1. Suppose $\mathbb{P}_{X \mid Y}$ is a conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$.
   Then we could write
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)]
   &= \sum_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}[f(X, Y) \mid Y = y] \mathbb{P}(Y = y) \\
   &= \sum_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, y) \, \mathbb{P}_{X \mid Y}(dx, y)\right) \mathbb{P}(Y = y).
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   The question then becomes how to compute $\mathbb{P}_{X \mid Y}$, and this depends on what you know about $X$ and $Y$ to begin with.
   However, one potential starting point is that this conditional distribution is determined by the condition
   $$
   \mathbb{P}(X \in B, Y \in C) = \sum_{y \in C} \left(\int_B \, \mathbb{P}_{X \mid Y}(dx, y)\right) \mathbb{P}(Y = y)
   $$
   for all Borel sets $B, C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

   It might be the case that you can compute a conditional density $p_{X \mid Y}$ of $X$ given $Y$ with respect to Lebesgue measure, in which case we would have
   $$
   \int_B \mathbb{P}_{X \mid Y}(dx, y) = \int_B p_{X \mid Y}(x, y) \, dx,
   $$
   and hence
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)]
   = \sum_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, y) p_{X \mid Y}(x, y) \, dx\right) \mathbb{P}(Y = y).
   $$
2. Now suppose $\mathbb{P}_{Y \mid X}$ is a conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$, and $p_X$ is the density of $X$ with respect to Lebesgue measure.
   In this case,
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)]
   = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, y) \, \mathbb{P}_{Y \mid X}(d y, x)\right) p_X(x) \, dx.
   $$
   Again, being able to compute $\mathbb{P}_{Y \mid X}$ requires you to know something about $X$ and $Y$ beforehand, but it is determined by the condition
   $$
   \mathbb{P}(X \in B, Y \in C) = \int_B \left(\int_C \, \mathbb{P}_{Y \mid X}(dy, x)\right) p_X(x) \, dx
   $$
   for all Borel sets $B, C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
   In this case, you can compute a conditional probability mass function $p_{Y \mid X}$ of $Y$ given $X$ (i.e., a conditional density with respect to counting measure) explictly by
   $$
   p_{Y \mid X}(y, x) = \mathbb{P}_{Y \mid X} (\{y\}, x)
   = \text{"}\mathbb{P}(Y = y \mid X = x)\text{"}.
   $$
   and hence
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)]
   = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\sum_{y \in \mathbb{R}} f(x, y) \, p_{Y \mid X}(y, x)\right) p_X(x) \, dx.
   $$

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!
Two questions: Does a joint probability measure always exist (even when one RV is continuous and the other discrete)?
You are using the joint density $f(x, y)$ here but in your comment below my answer you are saying that such a density does not exist. How does this fit together?

Comment: @guest1 a joint probability always exists: it's defined (using the notation I used) by $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(E) = \mathbb{P}((X, Y) \in E)$. And sorry if it caused confusion, but the $f$ that I used here is not a joint density but just some function whose expected value we want to compute

Comment: Great thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for asking so much later: But why do you integrate over y in the first equation after point 2.) ? Because Y is a discrete RV, so I would assume that you have to sum over it?

Comment: @guest1 No need to apologize :). The integral is with respect to $\mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X}(dy, x)$, which is a discrete measure (i.e., absolutely continuous with respect to counting measure). Integrals over such measures are the same as sums. In other words, any countable sum $\sum_{i\in I} a_i$ is the same as the integral $\int_I a_i \, \mu(di)$ where $\mu$ is counting measure. I chose to present the integral because it is a formula that holds generally, not just in the discrete case.

Comment: thanks again. So to say that $\mathbb{P}_{Y, X} is absolutely dontinuous w.r.t the counting measure, does that mean that it is a density (w.r.t counting measure)? And does that imply that every discrete probability distribution can be interpreted as a density?

Comment: Yes to both. To the second point, every discrete probability distribution has a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function), and that probability mass function is a density with respect to counting measure.

Comment: Ah thanks. Does that also mean that if we have a joint distribution of an absolutely continuous RV X and a discrete RV Y, $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}$ , that there always exists a density w.r.t the product of the Lebesgue and counting measure? Of what use could such a density be, however? Because we  cannot really integrate it using Rieman Integrals if the density is not w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, right?

Comment: I also dont exactly understand the equation $\int_B \mathbb{P}_{X|Y}(dx,y)=\int_B p_{X|Y}(x,y)dx. So first of all, how can there exist a probability distribution of an absolutley continuous (a.c.) RV if there wouldnt exit a density of it (you write "It might be the case that you can compute a conditional density"), because a distr of an a.c. RV is always defined as the integral over the density right? And what I neither understand is what is going on behind the scene in that equatliy? Shouldnt there be an additional integral because the integral of the denisty is the distribution?

Comment: Hi I am currently reading your answers again because I need it again atm. Since I find your answer very helpful, I wanted to ask if you can give me a recommendation for a text book or lecture notes, where the stuff you describe is presented in the same way as you did here? And another question: Does the formula in 1.) after "this conditional distribution is determined by the condition " only hold for sets of the form $B \times C$ but not generally for subsets of the product sigma algebra?

Comment: Most books on measure-theoretic probability should cover the material similarly. Personally, I like _Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course_ by Klenke and _A Modern Approach to Probability Theory_ by Fristedt and Gray. For your second question, yes: the formula I gave is a kind of Fubini-Tonelli formula. There are more complicated analogs for non-product sets

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. What would change in that formula for non-product sets?

Comment: Those kinds of formulas can be handled by various disintegration theorems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem

Comment: thank you! maybe you are interested in another question of mine that i posted here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734326/generalization-of-fubinis-theorem-for-joint-probability-measures?noredirect=1#comment10037075_4734326

Answer (score 3):

I am using slightly different notation that the OP in this answer.

This is a situation where the *law of iterated expectation* is very useful.  Let $Z=g(X,Y)$ denote the random variable whose expectation we wish to compute.  Then, the Law of Iterated Expectation tells us that

$$E[Z] = E[E[Z\mid Y]]$$

where $E[Z\mid Y]$ is a *random variable* that happens to be a function of the *discrete* random variable $Y$ that takes on values $\{y_1, y_2, \cdots\}$. Thus,
\begin{align}E[Z] &= \sum_i P(Y=y_i)E[Z\mid Y=y_i]\\
&= \sum_i P(Y=y_i) E[g(X,Y)\mid Y =y_i]\tag{1}\\
\end{align}

But, *given* that the value of $Y$ is $y_i$, $g(X,Y) = g(X,y_i)$ depends on $X$ alone, not on $Y$ whose value is fixed at $y_i$.  Consequently, we can compute $E[g(X,Y)\mid Y =y_i]$ using $f_{X\mid Y=y}(x \mid Y=y)$, the *conditional* density of $X$ given that $Y=y$.  Well, let $f(x,y)$ be a nonnegative function with support $\mathbb R\times \{y_1, y_2, \cdots\}$ such that for each $y_i$, $\int_\mathbb R f(x,y_i)\,\mathrm dx = P(Y = y_i)$, or equivalently,

$$f_{X\mid Y=y_i}(x \mid Y=y_i) = \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y_i)}{P(Y=y_i)}.$$

Similarly, the *conditional* mass function of $Y$ given that $X = x$ is

$$p_{Y \mid X = x]}(y_i) = \dfrac{f(x,y_i)}{\sum_j f(x,y_j).}$$

Note that $f(x,y)$ is *not* the joint *density* function of $X$ and $Y$;  $X$ and $Y$ are not jointly continuous random variables and do not enjoy a joint density function.  Then, $(1)$ simplifies to

\begin{align}
E[g(X,Y)] &= \sum_i P(Y=y_i) \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y_i)\dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y_i)}{P(Y=y_i)} \,\mathrm dx \\
&= \sum_i \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y_i) f_{X,Y}(x,y_i) \,\mathrm dx.\tag{2}\end{align}

I have no idea how to write $(2)$ in terms of of an integral with respect to the probability measure $P$ as in $\int \cdots\mathrm dP$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the last line you probably mean the conditional density right?
Also how would I write this in terms of an integral w.r.t. to the probability measure P, i.e., as something like $\int ... dP$?

Comment: @guest1 See revised answer.