# Joint probability measure

Tags: joint-distribution, measure-theory

I know from my measure theory class that for two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(\mathcal{X}_1, \mathcal{A}_1, \mu_1)$ and $(\mathcal{X}_2, \mathcal{A}_2, \mu_2)$ there exists a unique measure $\mu := \mu_1 \otimes \mu_2:\mathcal{A}_1 \otimes \mathcal{A}_2 \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ such that
$$ \mu_1 \otimes \mu_2(A_1 \times A_2) = \mu_1(A_1)\cdot \mu_2(A_2).$$
So my questions is what that means in probability theory, for the joint distribution (measure) of two random variables?
Is $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}$, the joint distribution of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ the same as $\mathbb{P}_{X}\otimes \mathbb{P}_{Y}$? Probably not, otherwise all random variables would be independent due to the above theorem, no?
But how do $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{X}\otimes \mathbb{P}_{Y}$ then relate to each other? (This is particularly needed to compute the expectation over the joint distribution)

Comment: The unique measure your theorem says exists with that multiplicative property  is the precisely that resulting for the two random variables being independent with respective measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.  Any other measure would not have that multiplicative property for all $A_1 \times A_2 \in \mathcal{A}_1 \otimes \mathcal{A}_2$

Comment: This independence leads (in one direction) to $\mathbb E_{X,Y}[X\cdot Y] = \mathbb E_{X}[X] \cdot \mathbb E_{Y}[Y]$ so long as all the expectations are finite

Comment: Exactly, but in general random variables are not independent. So why wouldnt this theorem apply to them?

Comment: How exactly would it apply?  All it would end up showing is that you have found *two* measures on the product: the original $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}$ and the one constructed by this theorem.  The theorem doesn't assert all joint measures are the same!

Comment: Well I thought that since the measure from the theorem is unique, it is the only measure on the product sigma algebra. And if we calculate a double integral with the theorem of Fubini, we always use the product measure from the theorem above, no? So if we calculate an expectation value then I would assume that we always use the product measure of the theorem above...

Comment: Pay attention to the "such that" after the word "unique"!

Comment: Okay so the measure is unique in that it is the only product measure that allows us to write it as a product of the two measures. But what about expectation values of dependent random variables? How can we calculate them, since we cannot make use of Fubini's theorem, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use Fubini's Theorem.  You appear to confuse the computation of multiple integrals with independence.  Independence amounts to saying a double integral splits into a product of two single integrals (and therefore you don't even need Fubini's help).

Comment: So I have understood Fubini's theorem as follows: If you have an integral w.r.t a product measure then you can write this as a double integral regarding the product of the two measures (as in the theorem I have written above) and furthermore the order of the integration can be interchanged. So I understood Fubini's theorem that I can only split up an integral over a product measure in case the product measure is given by the product of the individual measures (as given by the theorem above). Is this wrong?

Comment: @guest1 please see my [updated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/525342/97872) for how to compute expectations in the dependent case.

Comment: OK sorry for bringing this up once again. But here:
http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~beforres/PMath451/Course_Notes/Chapter7.pdf
in the product measure theorem it is said, that there always exists a measure on the product sigma algebra, such that $\pi(A \times B) = \mu(A) \nu(B)$. As long as the spaces are not sigma finite, that measure is not unique though. However, isnt the joint distribution of two random variables uniquely defined through the probability measure of the underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$? (it is just the pushforward measure under Z=(X, Y)?)

Comment: And if that joint probability distribution was unique, then it would necessarily need to be that measure that can be dissected as a product of the marginal measures - as one such measure always exists according to that theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Joint Distributions and Expectation

In general, the *joint distribution* of random variables $X$ and $Y$, defined on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ and taking values in measurable spaces $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$ and $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{C})$, respectively, is the probability measure defined on $(\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{C})$ by
$$
\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(E) = \mathbb{P}((X, Y) \in E)
$$
for all $E \in \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{C}$.

This is the same as the ordinary distribution of $(X, Y) : \Omega \to \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ when viewed as a single random variable defined on $\Omega$.

Also, $X$ and $Y$ are said to be *independent* if it holds that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \in B, Y \in C) = \mathbb{P}(X \in B) \mathbb{P}(Y \in C)
$$
for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $C \in \mathcal{C}$.

The independence condition can be rephrased in terms of the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$: $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if
$$
\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(B \times C) = \mathbb{P}_X(B) \mathbb{P}_Y(C)
$$
for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $C \in \mathcal{C}$. That is, if and only if
$$
\mathbb{P}_{X, Y} = \mathbb{P}_X \otimes \mathbb{P}_Y.
$$
Thus, the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the product measure of the (marginal) distributions of $X$ and $Y$ precisely in the case that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
If $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, then their joint distribution is not the product measure of the marginal distributions.

### Computing Expectations over Joint Distributions

If $X$ and $Y$, as above, are independent and $f : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function (satisfying either non-negativity or integrability with respect to $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}$), then Fubini's theorem allows you to compute
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)]
&= \int_\Omega f(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega) &&
\text{(def. of expectation)}
\\
&= \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}} f(x, y) \, \mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(d(x, y)) &&
\text{(change of variables)}
\\
&= \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}} f(x, y) \, \mathbb{P}_X\otimes\mathbb{P}_Y(d(x, y)) &&\text{(independence)}
\\
&= \int_{\mathcal{Y}} \left(\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x, y) \, \mathbb{P}_X(dx)\right) \, \mathbb{P}_Y(dy) &&\text{(Fubini's theorem)}
\end{aligned}
$$
However, if $X$ are $Y$ are not independent, then this argument won't work. Instead, if you want to break an expectation of $f(X,Y)$ into an integral over $\mathcal{X}$ followed by an integral over $\mathcal{Y}$, as we did above, you need to know something about the [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability#Conditional_probability_distribution) of $X$ given $Y$.

For what follows, suppose $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B})$ and $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{C})$ are "sufficiently nice" measurable spaces, meaning that they admit conditional distributions (this will happen for most spaces in practice; a sufficient condition is being standard Borel).

Then if $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y} : \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{Y} \to [0, 1]$ is a version of the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$, then we can proceed similarly to the calculations above:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)]
&= \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}} f(x, y) \, \mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(d(x, y))
\\
&= \int_{\mathcal{Y}} \left(\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x, y) \, \mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y}(dx, y)\right) \, \mathbb{P}_Y(dy) \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y) \mid Y]]
\end{aligned}
$$
(in fact, the formula $\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y) \mid Y]]$ holds even without considering conditional distributions ([proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_general_case)), but it's arguably harder to compute in that case).

If $X$ and $Y$ *are* independent, then it happens that $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y}(B, y) = \mathbb{P}_X(B)$ for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathbb{P}_Y$-almost every $y \in Y$.
In this case, the calculation reduces to the first computation above.

In practice, the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y}$ will usually be given by a conditional density $p_{X\mid Y} : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} \to [0, \infty)$ of $X$ given $Y$ with respect to some dominating measure $\mu$ on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$, yielding
$$
E[f(X, Y)]
= \int_{\mathcal{Y}} \left(\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x, y) p_{X \mid Y}(x, y) \, \mu(dx)\right) \, \mathbb{P}_Y(d y).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume that you mean $E\in \mathcal{B}\bigotimes\mathcal{C}$ after the first equation?

Comment: So I dont understand why there can be different product measures since the theorem states that the product measure is unique? Also the theorem of Fubini depends on the theorem from my question, no? So that would mean that for dependent random variables I could not use Fubini's theorem to calculate the expectation, right?

Comment: @guest1 You're right, I fixed that typo. Regarding your second question, the uniqueness of the product measure $\mu \otimes \nu$ is with regard to the condition $(\mu \otimes \nu)(A \times B) = \mu(A)\nu(B)$. That is, there's only one measure satisfying that equation (under conditions like $\sigma$-finiteness), but there can be many others that don't satisfy it. Also, there are versions of Fubini's theorem that hold for non-product measures (e.g., [disintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), which is related to conditional probabilities)

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer!
What are the requirements/conditions that a conditional distribution exists?

Comment: @guest1 a sufficient condition on the underlying measurable spaces is that they are [standard Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space): a measurable space $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$ is standard Borel if there exists a metric $d$ on $\mathcal{X}$ such that $(\mathcal{X}, d)$ is a complete, separable metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$

Comment: Thanks!
So what I was wondering now: Using the non-measure theoretic way to calculate the joint expectation, I would just do: $\int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}} f(x, y) \mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x,y) dxdy$. But how do I get there without somehow using an independence assumption? Because I cannot split up the integral over $\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}}$ into a double integral without splitting the joint probability distribution into a conditional and a marginal, as you did in the dependent case, right?

Comment: And two questions to the last equation: So is that measure $\mu$ in probability theory not always the Lebesgue measure then? And is $\mathbb{P}(y)=\mathbb{P}_Y(y)$ here?

Comment: @guest1 Thanks, $\mathbb{P}(dy)$ was a typo; it's fixed.

I'm not sure what you mean by "non measure-theoretic way". In practice you compute the expected value of a function of two random variables by conditioning on one of them: $E[f(X,Y)]=E[E[f(X, Y) | Y]]$. The calculation usually reduces to a concrete instance of the last equation in my answer. This works whether or not the variables are independent (it's just redundant if you know beforehand that they're independent).

Lastly, the dominating measure $\mu$ in probability theory isn't necessarily Lebesgue measure, but it often is.

Comment: What I mean by the "non measure theoretic way" is the way in which you dont compute the expectation value as $\int X dP$ but as $\int x p(x) dx$ (for a continuous RV). And I was wondering how you get from $\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}}f(x,y)\mathbb{P}(d(x, y))$ to the expression $\int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x, y) p_{X, Y}(x, y) dxdy$ for two countinuous RVs with joint density $p_{X, Y}(x, y) $. Because we somehow would have to transform the single integral into a double integral

Comment: @guest1 two things are happening there: the definition of "density", and Fubini's theorem. If $p$ is a density of $P$ with respect to a measure $\mu$, then $\int f\,dP=\int fp\,d\mu$. Next, if the integral exists *and* is over a product space $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$ *and* the dominating measure $\mu$ is a product measure $\nu\otimes\lambda$ (as is the case for Lebesgue measure), then the integral can be written $\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}}fp\,d(\nu\otimes\lambda)=\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\left(\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x,y)p(x,y)\,\mu(dx)\right)\,\lambda(dy)$ by Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Ah great thanks. So the reason then why this is not possible for a joint distribution of a continuous and a discrete random variable, is because they cannot have a joint density w.r.t. do the Lebesgue or counting measure?
And by dominating measure you mean that the measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t. to another measure (the dominating measure)?

Comment: @guest1 that’s correct

Comment: So another question: Of course it holds by definition that $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x, y)=\mathbb{P}_{X|Y=y}(x)\mathbb{P}_{Y}(y)$. However, how is it justified to just write this expression as infinitesimals, i.e., as $d\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x, y)=d\mathbb{P}_{X|Y=y}(x)d\mathbb{P}_{Y}(y)$, which you did in the case where there is no independence?

Comment: @guest1 there are several ways of proving that result. Some people call it a generalized version of Fubini's theorem. Other people cite the [disintegration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem). For a concrete reference, it can be derived from the "product measure theorem" in [*Probability and Measure Theory* (Second Edition) by Ash and Doléans-Dade](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Probability_and_Measure_Theory/GkqQoRpCO2QC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA102&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Great thank you for the reference. Is it also possible to do it the other way round? So can I do something like: $\int g(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{X|Y=y}(y) = \int g(x, y) \frac{d\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(x,y)}{d\mathbb{P}_{Y}(y)}$?

Comment: Sorry it should read $d\mathbb{P}_{X| Y=y}(x)$

Comment: The measures $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}$ and $\mathbb{P}_Y$ are defined on different measurable spaces, so unfortunately the Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(x,y)/d\mathbb{P}_{Y}(y)$ isn't well-defined there.

Comment: Okay but why can I write $\int g(x, y) \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}dxdy$ but not $\int g(x, y) \frac{d\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x, y)}{d\mathbb{P}_Y(y)}$? Shouldnt this be equivalent?

Comment: I.e., isnt both equal to $\int g(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{X|Y=y}(x)$?

Comment: And maybe to get to my actual point: For a discrete RV $Y$ and a continuous RV $X$ I try to re-write $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$. If both $Y$ and $X$ were continuous, I could write $\frac{1}{f_Y(y)}\int y f_{X, Y}(x, y)dy$, right? Can I also do that somehow, if $Y$ is discrete?

Comment: Sorry, to ask you that many questions!

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm glad to help :). Regarding "$\int g(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{X|Y=y}(x) = \int g(x, y) \frac{d\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(x,y)}{d\mathbb{P}_{Y}(y)}$", it's unclear to me what the integral on the right means. That is, what is the measure being used to compute it? Regarding "Can I also do that somehow, if $Y$ is discrete?", you could write it as $\sum_y y \mathbb{P}(Y = y \mid X = x)$, where "$\mathbb{P}(Y=y\mid X=x)$" is alternative notation for a conditional density $f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x)$

Comment: Yes I am also not sure what the measure would be in $\int g(x, y) \frac{d\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x,y)}{d\mathbb{P}_Y(y)}$ I guess that is one of my problems :D I am just confused about that fact that I could write this integral regarding the densities, i.e., as $\int g(x,y)\frac{f_{X, Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dxdy$, but not regarding the probabilty measures. However in other cases, for instance the integral over the joint measure, the following two expressions are equal: $\int g(x, y) f_{X, Y}(x,y) dxdy=\int g(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x, y)$

Comment: It might be helpful to indicate what space you're integrating over. That is, is $\int$ supposed to be interpreted as $\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}}$ and $x$ and $y$ are both being integrated over? Or is $\int$ supposed to be interpreted as $\int_{\mathcal{X}}$ or $\int_{\mathcal{Y}}$ and one of $x$ and $y$ is fixed and the other is being integrated over? The answer is unclear to me in some of the integrals in this thread, so I think if you clarify that, it'll be easier to figure out what the integrals are supposed to be

Comment: Oh thanks for that comment, because I am actually not sure myself. So I defnitely mean $\int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{X}}g(x,y) f_{X, Y}(x, y) dxdy$. But I am not sure regarding the other integral. Probably it would be $\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}}g(x, y)d\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x, y)$. And with $\int g(x, y) \frac{d\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(x, y)}{d\mathbb{P}_y(y)}$ I really dont know. But that also does not exist anyway if I understood correctly.

Comment: Hi so I am wondering if the change of variables formula holds only for product-like sets of the form $B\times C$ or for more general sets $E$ from the product sigma algebra?

Comment: The change-of-variables formula here is an instance of the so-called "law of the unconscious statistician": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Measure-theoretic_formulation , it's not related to product spaces

Comment: thank you. Is this something different than the change of variables formula of pushforward measures?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula