# Could it make sense to calculate the "distance correlation" among two probability measures (probability distributions)?

Tags: probability, distributions, measure-theory

**Introduction.** I post here the same question that I asked on math.stackexchange, since it might be more relevant to this forum: [Could it make sense to calculate the "distance correlation" among two probability measures (probability distributions)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771903/could-it-make-sense-to-calculate-the-distance-correlation-among-two-probabilit).

**Question.** Would it make sense to calculate the ["distance correlation" introduced by Székely et al.(2007)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25464608) (also here on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation)) among two probability measures $P$ and $Q$, i.e. $\mathcal{R}(P,Q)$, rather than between two random vectors $X$ and $Y$, as stated on the Székely et al.(2007) paper?

**Edited after the Christian Hennig's Answer.** @Christian Hennig, thanks! Do you mean something like this?

1. **If** $X \sim P$ and $Y \sim Q$ and
2. **If** (from @Artem Mavrin's reply in [Joint probability measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525334/joint-probability-measure/525342#525342) - note that I used your notation for the joint probability, i.e. $J$)

> the *joint distribution* of random variables $X$ and $Y$, defined on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, J)$
> and taking values in measurable spaces $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$ and $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{C})$, respectively, is the probability measure defined on $(\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{B} \otimes\mathcal{C})$ by $$ J_{X, Y}(E) = J((X, Y) \in E) $$ for all $E \in \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{C}$.

3. **Then**, we can calculate the correlation distance among two probability measures $P$ and $Q$, i.e. $\mathcal{R}(P,Q)=\mathcal{R}\left({J_{X, Y}(E)}\right)$.

But then,  I would not know how to connect $\mathcal{R}(P,Q)=\mathcal{R}\left({J_{X, Y}(E)}\right)$ to $\mathcal{R}(X,Y)$, which is (the latter) what stated on the Székely et al.(2007) paper... I think I did not get this connection: $\mathcal{R}(P,Q) = \mathcal{R}(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just specify the distributions $P$ and $Q$ (of the two random variables $X$ and $Y$), you don't specify the dependence structure between them, which is essential for distance correlation. You'd need to define it depending on the *joint distribution* (let's call it $J$) of $X$ and $Y$, so you can have ${\cal R}(J)$, which would be the same thing as defining it based on $X$ and $Y$ (involving the dependence structure between them).

Comment: +1 - The same is true for the ordinary Pearson correlation

Comment: Thanks @Christian Hennig! I wrote my comment in the main question :-)
By chance, do you have a reference to look up?

Comment: Thanks @Henry! I try to ask the same as to Christian Henning.. By chance, do you have a reference to suggest about the comment you wrote?

Comment: @Ommo Saying "Pearson correlation is affected by the dependence structure" is not controversial: it is zero when the two random variables are independent (easily proved since the covariance will then be zero) so when it is not zero you can say they are not independent.  The assertion with "distance correlation" is that you can also say that if it is zero then they are independent, which is not generally automatically the case with Pearson correlation.

Comment: @Ommo Regarding your edit, it is wrong to write ${\cal R}(P,Q)$ (and your cited response doesn't do that), because this suggests that ${\cal R}$ can be computed from just knowing $P$ and $Q$, but not their dependence structure. The definition of ${\cal J}_{X,Y}$ is fine though. I don't have a reference. I'd suspect that people who generally understand this part of probability theory would find this obvious and wouldn't bother to write it down in a proper publication. (It's still a valid question of course if you're not that much into probability theory.)

Comment: Thanks @Henry for your comment.. Yes, that is the "power" of the distance correlation.. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChristianHennig! So, if I understood correctly, I can just say what I reported in the excerpt of "Joint probability measure" (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525334/joint-probability-measure/525342#525342)  i.e. my point (2) in my edited question, but how can I make the connection between the two probability measures, $P$ and $Q$, and $\mathcal{R}(X,Y)$ (the latter from the Székely et al.(2007) paper)? OK, by using the joint distribution, $J_{X,Y}$, but how exactly? ....the connection might be silly/trivial, but it is not fully clear to me yet...sorry

Comment: @Ommo The two are just the same thing by definition. ${\cal R}(J)$ is just defined by what goes on between random variables $(X,Y)$ that are jointly distributed according to $J$. So you wouldn't define $ {\cal R}(J)$ in a different way and then somehow "connect" this to ${\cal R}(X,Y)$, rather you define  ${\cal R}(X,Y)$ as you know it, and then have the right to call this thing also $ {\cal R}(J)$. The thing that you may get wrong here is the expectation that these should somehow look very different, yet still be the same. They're not different in any sense.

Comment: Ahh, ok, got it, many thanks! Yes, I thought to have/get two different entities here, that should be somehow connected... :-) So, probably, it is just sufficient to say $X \sim P$ and $Y \sim Q$ and introduce $J$. Just for the notation, maybe I could write, but I am not quite sure: $\mathcal{R}(J_{X,Y}) = \mathcal{R}((X \sim P,Y \sim Q))$

Comment: @Ommo You "could" write whatever you want, even if it's wrong; but I don't understand why you're not happy with just writing ${\cal R}(X,Y)$ in the first place.

Comment: Yes yes, I am OK with $\mathcal{R}(X,Y)$.. I was just "thinking out loud"... thanks :-)